# How does pybind11 methods end up calling functions from the shared library?

Tags: python, pybind11

I can make as much out as its [build system](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-manually) generates a shared object, and also a Python module as a proxy to that shared object. But how does the Python runtime end up doing a `dlopen` of the generated shared object and bind Python method calls on to corresponding functions in the shared library?

I also found a reference in [Python's import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-path-based-finder) about shared libraries, but nothing beyond that. Does CPython treat `.so` files in the module path as Python modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing `import module` Python will look for files with various extensions that could be python modules. That can be `module.py`, but also `module.so` (on Linux) or `module.pyd` (on Windows).

When loading a shared object, Python will load it like any dynamic library and then it will call the module's init method: It must be named `PyInit_{module_name_here}` and exported in the shared library.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html).